# rails schema version does not reflect latest migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

using rails 4, i've added a migration, bringing my schema up to version **20150207205305**

I decided I no longer needed this migration and reverted all of my changes by removing it and checking back out the master branch -

but I have found that when running `rake db:reset; rake db:migrate` the schema.rb version is still set to my non existent migration, version **20150207205305**, with the old (and nonexistent) migration still taking effect on my schema.

What am I missing? Why is the old migration, even though it doesn't exist, still taking affect after db reset + migrate?

```
$ rm -f db/schema.rb
$ be rake db:drop; be rake db:create;
$ ls db/migrate/ 

20141222203059_create_posts.rb 
20141223152011_create_users.rb 
20150121231334_create_api_keys.rb 
20150121235406_drop_user_password_and_add_password_digest.rb 
20150204032843_create_carts.rb 
20150204032904_create_categories.rb 
20150204033026_create_customers.rb 
20150204033441_create_items.rb 
20150204033614_create_sales.rb 
20150204033708_create_shows.rb 
20150204034028_create_venues.rb

$ be rake db:migrate
$ be rake db:migrate:status

database:

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20141222203059  Create posts
   up     20141223152011  Create users
   up     20150121231334  Create api keys
   up     20150121235406  Drop user password and add password digest
   up     20150204032843  Create carts
   up     20150204032904  Create categories
   up     20150204033026  Create customers
   up     20150204033441  Create items
   up     20150204033614  Create sales
   up     20150204033708  Create shows
   up     20150204034028  Create venues
   up     20150207195208  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150207200152  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150207205305  ********** NO FILE **********
```

note difference in schema number:

```
$ git diff db/schema.rb
-ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150204034028) do 
+ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150207205305) do
```

**update/solution**
we were able to trace this back to an invalid database.yml, where nil was coming through for the db name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake db:reset` doesn't update the schema file, it just re-applies it and runs the seeds, the only commands that do update the schema file are (as far as i know) `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:rollback`

You should have ran `rake db:rollback` before deleting/reverting the migration file, if you want to fix this you could checkout the old migration file, rollback then remove it again.

Comment: i realize this - I reset and ran migrations, ive edited my question to include this. aslo the migration file no longer exists, it was in a separate branch, - since I am resetting, this will drop and set up db - then I can just rerun migrations. but non existent migration still takes effect

Comment: running a second `rake db:migrate` won't do any thing, because the schema version in the `schema.rb` is already later than the latest migration file you have, ` rake db:migrate` only increments the version, it can't decrement it.

Comment: if i reset and migrate, shouldnt my schema have latest migration as version number?

Comment: I think reset is like `rake db:schema:load` and `rake db:seed`, it doesn't touch the schema file, it just reads it and applies it

Comment: right - rake db:reset which drops and then recreates the database and includes your seeds.rb - so runnign migrations after that should reflect lastest migration, in upwards motion. my shema doesn't - its as if my schema is applying the deleted migration, even after reset.

Comment: only if the schema version is smaller than the biggest migration version, otherwise no changes are applied.

Comment: but thats whats happening. my schema version is bigger then one I have migration available for. does not reflect last migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70487/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-lfender6445).

Comment: mohammed and I were able to trace this back to an invalid `database.yml`, where nil was coming through for the db name